# How Do I Parse this html table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to parse below html table and get the contents from it.

The html looks like this..

```
<body id="up">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td align="left">
                <a href="http://example.com/index.php"><font color="#990033">Back</font></a>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <a href="http://example.com/feedback.php"><font color="#990033">Feedback</font></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <br><br>
        <center>
        <table width="100%" bgcolor="#CCCC99">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <font color="#666633">
                        This is what I want <br>
                        19:09, 30 Nov 14 <br>
                        Journey Over<br>Reached SBC at 19:00 <br>
                        <br>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </center>
    <img src="./ga.php">


</body>
```

I want to extract the content and have it in a variable.

"
This is what I want 
                        19:09, 30 Nov 14 
                        Journey Over
Reached SBC at 19:00 
                        
"
It would be good if I may get value per line.

I have tried different methods of getting to the value, but sometimes it prints null, or I get some error.
How can I get those strings?

Thanks,
Hvr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [soup.select](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to the `td` tags:

```
In [26]: import bs4 as bs
In [27]: soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(open('data', 'rb').read())

In [28]: [list(td.stripped_strings) for td in soup.select('table tbody tr td')][-1]
Out[28]: 
[u'This is what I want',
 u'19:09, 30 Nov 14',
 u'Journey Over',
 u'Reached SBC at 19:00']
```

Comment: thanks ..but how can I use the line [list(td.stripped_strings) for td in soup.select('table tbody tr td')][-1] in the python script to assign the lines to separate variables.

Comment: You could assign all the strings to one variable: `data = [...]`, and then access the individual strings with list indexing: `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc. This may be better than giving each line a separate variable name, because in general you may not know how many items are in the list. If you know for sure that there are four items in the list, then you could use `a, b, c, d = [...]`.

Comment: I am able to get to the node using below expression. 
strong = soup('table')[1].findAll('tbody')[0].findAll('tr')[0].findAll('td')[0]

This gives me an output of

<td align="center">
<font color="#666633">
                                                This is what I want <br />
                                                19:09, 30 Nov 14 <br />
                                                Journey Over<br />Reached SBC at 19:00 <br />
<br />
</font>
</td>
After this I am unable to seperate the lines..I am not able to use either strong.string, dur to I guess presence of <br>..

Comment: Why not use the solution I posted?

Comment: I switched my pi and got bs4. But when I do data = [list(td.stripped_strings) for td in soup.select('table tbody tr td')][-1]
it gives me an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range                                                  what should I do in this case?

Comment: I tried with data = = [list(td.stripped_strings) for td in soup.select('table tbody tr td')] and then tried printing data..but it gives [].

Comment: Is the HTML you are parsing *exactly* the one you posted, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, html was changed and had no tbody tag. So I changed the expression ('table tr td') and now I am able to use the way you suggested. Thanks for suggesting this method.